# Getting '407 Proxy Authentication requires' error in mechanize

Tags: python, mechanize

```
import mechanize

b=mechanize.Browser()
b.set_handle_robots(False)
b.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
b.open("http://www.google.co.in")
b.select_form(nr=0)
b['q']='alpha'
b.submit()
x=b.response()
print x.read()
```

The code above works normally. However when I change http to https, I get a "407 Proxy Authentication Required" error. What is the reason behind this and how to fix this? Also `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` environment variables are set and I am on a Linux machine.

Comment: What are the outputs of `echo $http_proxy` and `echo $https_proxy` on a terminal?

Comment: We can infer that your proxy requires you to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

Some applications are case sensitive to environment variables, so better off set all of them in your `/etc/environment` file in the following way:

```
http_proxy=http://username:password@host:port_no
https_proxy=https://username:password@host:port_no
HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@host:port_no
HTTPS_PROXY=https://username:password@host:port_no
```

Remember to set the protocol before the username.

Comment: It does not work.
Also if applications are case sensitive to environment variables, then in my case http should not work. But it is working.